# R: RMariaDB not available for 3.4.0 - How connect to MySQL from R v 3.4.0?

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb

The RMySQL package notes recommend using RMariaDB instead. RMariaDB package says that it is not available for R3.4.0, and does not install.

What is the best way to connect to a MySQL database if I'm running R v3.4.0?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like `RMariaDB` is on CRAN yet. You can install the dev version from github:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/RMariaDB")
```

Or you can use `RMySQL` for now, and keep your eye on further developments from `RMariaDB`.